# Electron-packager does not package node modules which names are started from "@"

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I create desktop application by using electron, and tried electron-packager.
But electron-packager doesn't package node modules which names are started from "@" (Example: @turf, @mapbox)

In node_modules folder of developing folder, I can find "@turf" and "@mapbox".
[image: Developing folder]

But after running

```
>electron-packager . MaplatEditor --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --electron-version=1.7.9
```

Created package never includes "@turf" and "@mapbox".
And also, it's depending modules are also not included.
[image: Package's node modules]

My package.json includes "@turf", so it is not setting error.

```
{
  "name": "MaplatEditor",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "lib/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@turf/turf": "^4.6.1",
    "argv": "0.0.2",
    "async": "^2.5.0",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "electron-json-storage": "^3.2.0",
    "file-url": "^2.0.2",
    "fs-extra": "^3.0.1",
    "imagemagick": "^0.1.3",
    "mapshaper": "^0.4.31",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "wellknown": "^0.5.0"
  }
}
```

How can I package such @-started modules into application package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I updated @Turf module for latest version, then electron-packager worked well.
I don't know why, but it looks not the issue of electron-packager...